# Java Match string format

Tags: java, regex, string

So I want to match a string to a simple mask but I would like to avoid using regex because my client have access to this mask and can change it.

Is it possible to have a string matches something like #####-000?

Or I have no choice but to convert my simple mask to regex ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us an example where you want to match it?

Comment: This looks like a number format but in case it isn't you'd either have to convert it to a regex (shouldn't be too hard) or find/create a matching utility.

Comment: @BenjaminLücking I want to match it like: 
12345-000 is true, 
12345-001 is false, 
1234-000 is false. ( is that what you meant? )

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, that is what I thought :/

Comment: The regex wouldn't be that hard: if `#` means a number then just use it like `input.matchs("#####-000".replaceAll("#","[0-9]"))` which should result int the expression `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-000`. Ofc you could also count the `#` and replace the while sequence with like `[0-9]{5}` instead.

Comment: If you want to check if a String matches a specific mask, you could iterate through every character in that String end check if the first characters are numbers and the remaining characters are -000

Comment: @Thomas I think I will do that, It is pretty easy as you write it!

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question (and the comments) the right way, you could do the following:

- Split your string at '-'
- Check if string before '-' has length 5 and is numeric (StringUtils.isNumeric(...))
- Check if the string after '-' equals '000'